# How can I link a second database for processing times in my job shop simulation to vary service station times based on job IDs?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

**My Question:**
How can i link another database for processing times, enabling distinct times to be called in service stations according to job IDs.

**What i've done so far:**
[This is my model, where the sequence for the jobs are based on a DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sehv6.png)

[this is my Job Agent, where the collection of ArrayList->String and the counter are in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZsFP.png)

**My DB for the Processing Times:**
I want to get the right ProcessingTime for the right Job at the Service Stations. Both DB have the column jobs and jobpt with the same IDs, both of type int.

[ProcessingTimes DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsVUs.png)

**What i've tried, but didn't work:**
I tried to create a new agent named 'ProcessingTimes' and add it to the 'Job' agent in order to access the data through a collection, but unfortunately, it didn't work.