# Can someone show/ explain me the steps for the second DB connection with the Processing Time Agent?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I saw this post few days ago: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162407/routing-agents-through-specific-resources-in-anylogic?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top). I have the same Problem: I need to connect another Agent with DB Parameters to my Job Agent. Here is the explanation of this post:

- Create another agent for the second table (call the agent ProcessingTime and table processing_time) and add it to the Job agent and then load it from database filtering on p_jobid as shown in the picture:

[image: The Picture]

I tried the same, but i think i miss something. I didn't get a connection.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. This is a place for specific technical questions. If you are looking for broader "how do I do X" responses, you should use the LinkedIn forum, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community and this for SOF specifically: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Hey Benjamin, I have asked a technical question regarding this issue: (see the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309981/how-can-i-link-a-second-database-for-processing-times-in-my-job-shop-simulation). Unfortunately, I have not received any response or anything else.

Comment: You may want to shorten that, we are all happy to help but extremely busy. If I read a question, I give it maybe 30-60 sec attention. If I cannot answer it with 1 word or 1-2 sentences, I often don't go deeper due to lack of time. Learn to design your questions that way and you get answers in no time. If you have a big fat complicted problem, break it up into tiny bits and advance that way :)

Comment: Hey @Benjamin i hope this is short enough. Maybe you can help me. :D

Comment: no idea what you mean, sorry. Seems like you confuse filtering and agent creation, tbh. Either filter data first and then create agents from it. Or create agents and link them according to your needs... kinda confusing, tbh

Comment: Maybe i can clarify my Problem. I already have an agent (Job with pop: job). i use the agent job with DB machine sequence to get the right sequence for my Jobs an let them go trough the flow chart in Main. Now i want to creater another Agent to get the processing Times vom another DB and link them to the jobs agent. All because i cant choose 2 Agents going trough the Service Flow Chart blocks in Main. Because i only can choose 1 agent type in advanced section of the service stations.

Comment: totally different problem. First, no need for creating agents for processing times. Second: you can always select `Agent` in the flow chart property to accept any agent, then use type-casting (`instanceof`) to check for specific types... but I think your real question is just something entirely different. Maybe "how can I store processing times for different machine types in my job agents?"??

Comment: Yes! How can i store processing times for different machine types in my job agents? Thats what i need. I've tried to use type-casting. I select Agent in the flow chart property and tried to get to the paramter value from my Job agent. I've tried to use: Code: if (agent instanceof Job ) ((Job)agent).maschine1 = delayTime;>

Comment: Check my workshop: https://youtu.be/OWwjKqKUA1A?si=7TUTQoGhqYG3SF8q . You need to first understand some basic OOP concepts and agent architecture. There are 1000 different ways *how*  to do it, but none is as trivial as some drag-n-drop . You can have a LinkedHashMap of machine-vs-process time, but if that doesn't mean anything, you need to catchup on basics first, tbh